# Robotium waitForFragmentByTag ignored when activity finishes

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotium, android-gradle-plugin

I'm writing a Robotium test to catch an existing bug where the action bar home button exits the app instead of popping the current fragment.  Unfortunately my test is passing, when I am expecting it to fail.

I was hoping that the final `waitForFragmentByTag` line in my test below should detect that the activity was finished instead of displaying a specific fragment.

I'm confident that `clickOnActionBarHomeButton` is finishing the activity instead of popping the fragment.

```
public void testBackToLandingPage() {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activity.getClass());
    activity.startActivity(intent);
    assertTrue(solo.waitForFragmentByTag("landingfragment"));

    solo.clickOnButton("Create Account");
    assertTrue(solo.waitForFragmentByTag("createaccountfragment"));

    // Check the hardware back button takes you back to the landing page
    solo.goBack();
    assertTrue(solo.waitForFragmentByTag("landingfragment"));

    solo.clickOnButton("Create Account");
    assertTrue(solo.waitForFragmentByTag("createaccountfragment"));

    // Check the action bar back/up button takes you back to the landing page
    solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
    assertTrue(solo.waitForFragmentByTag("landingfragment"));
}
```

The best option I've found so far is to add this check after `clickOnActionBarHomeButton`:

```
assertFalse(solo.getCurrentActivity().isFinishing());
```

It seems like I may need a custom waitForFragmentByTag method which always does both assertions, otherwise I may miss cases where my activity finishes unexpectedly.

Does Robotium already have a method to cover this scenario?  Am I reinventing the wheel?

I'm using Robotium 5.0.1 and am testing on an OS 4.4.2 emulator.

Comment: What waitForFragment does is: "This first searches through fragments that are currently added to the manager's activity; if no such fragment is found, then all fragments currently on the back stack associated with this ID are searched."

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It looks like this is a bug that was fixed in robotium 5.2.1, but I can't find any documentation to that effect.  I did find a related bug (https://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/detail?id=589) though that was fixed in 5.2.1.